# How to check if a variable doesn't start with a certain string in GitHub yaml file

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

In my yaml file I can check if a variable starts with a string by doing the following:

```
- name: Testing negation of startsWith
  if: startsWith(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'dog')
  run: echo "This job is dog"
  shell: cmd
```

I want to do something like this in Github in my yaml file to check if a variable doesn't start with a certain string except doing something like this will give a red line under cat saying tag suffix cannot contain flow indicator characters.

```
- name: Testing negation of startsWith
   if: !(startsWith(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'cat'))
   run: echo "This job is not a cat"
   shell: cmd
```

I also tried doing the following but it says Unrecognized function: 'not'

```
- name: Testing negation of startsWith
  if: not (startsWith(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'cat'))
  run: echo "This job is not a cat"
  shell: cmd
```

There should be an easy way to check if a variable doesn't start with a certain value given that checking for the positive case exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following syntax instead of wrapping the condition in quotes:

```
if: ${{ !startsWith(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'cat') }}
```

This will avoid linter errors

Answer (score 0):

So I just found out putting "" outside of !startsWith does the trick

```
- name: Testing negation of startsWith
  if: "!startsWith(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'cat')"
  run: echo "This job is not cat"
  shell: cmd
```

I made sure to test for both positive and negative and it gave the expected output. I don't know if this is documented on GitHub but it really should. If you want to do multiple statements then you need to enclose everything in quotes. For example

```
- name: Testing negation of startsWith
  if: "!startsWith(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'cat') && startsWith(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'dog')"
  run: echo "This job is not cat or a dog"
  shell: cmd
```